# Ways of getting 20% of elements in array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, random

I have an array of n elements and I need to get random 20% of those elements into another array. Is there any function which can achieve this?

Currently what I can think of is this:

```
foreach ($orders as $order) {
    if (rand(1, 100) > 80) {
        echo('20%');
    } else {
        echo('80%');
    }
}
```

Is there a more optimal way?

Comment: @The50 this won't get 20% of array elements, it might get more than that or less than that sometimes. You're just randomly getting a number, not getting 20% of random elements.

Comment: no in bulit function but can be done easily with `count()` `floor()`, `range()` and loop

Comment: Do you have to get exactly half? notice that in your example you get 20% by statistic and not `n/5`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) the array and then take the first 20% elements.

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
shuffle($array);    

$twenty = array_slice($array, 0, floor(count($array) / 5));
$eighty = array_slice($array, floor(count($array) / 5));
```

Comment: Yes, this does the trick, but how can I save the other 80% of elements left out? I need them also, as another array.

Comment: You can use array_slice again to the the other part of the array.

Comment: If you use `array_splice()` then you wouldn't have to slice twice.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is probably to use [`shuffle`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php):

```
shuffle($orders);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($orders) / 5; $i++) {
    // do something with the first 20% of elements
}
for (; $i < count($orders); $i++) {
    // do something with the rest of the array
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To get two arrays by one function call, use array_splice function. After

```
shuffle($array);
$twenty = array_splice($array, floor(count($array) / 5 * 4));
```

$twenty will held 1/5 of source array and $array - other items

Answer (score 0):

Shuffle is the simplest solution for this case

```
$array = [1,2,3,4]
shuffle($array);
$firstSlice = array_slice($array , 0 , count($array)/2);
$secondSlice = array_slice($array , count($array)/2 , count($array));
```